# SurfaceTexture Android Camera2

Tags: java, android

Goodnight

Someone knows a way to create a Surface Texture as if it were the one that can be obtained with the TextureView with the method getSurfaceTexture ()

```
mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()
```

I'm trying to make the code to record with the Api camera2 without having a preview (just use a button), but with the surfaceTexture that I create without using the Textureview the videos that I record usually go well for about 5 seconds and then the rest of the time of the video is that frozen frame. (The mPreview size that I use is obtained with the chooseOptimalSize () of the example of google using as width and height the dimensions of the cell phone screen)

```
SurfaceTexture texture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(),mPreviewSize.getHeight());
mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();


Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
surfaces.add(previewSurface);
mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);


// Set up Surface for the MediaRecorder
Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);
```